# Comparison query on nested date partition in Presto/Athena

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena

I have parquet data stored on S3, partitioned in the format that Hive understands

```
s3://<base_path>/year=2019/month=11/day=08/files.pq
```

The table schema also specifies `year, month, day` as partition fields.

Is it possible to comparison queries, specifically `LIKE, IN, BETWEEN` on dates, with this organization of data? An AWS [Athena best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/) blog seems to suggest its possible (`SELECT count(*) FROM lineitem WHERE l_shipdate >= '1996-09-01' AND l_shipdate < '1996-10-01'`), but I could not figure out how to specify the composite field (`l_shipdate` in query), either during table creation or during query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it doesn’t look very elegant)

```sql
SELECT col1, col2
FROM my_table 
WHERE CAST(date_parse(concat(CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)),'-',
                             CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)),'-',
                             CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2))
                             ), '%Y-%m-%d') as DATE) 
BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND DATE '2018-01-31'
```

Comment: Do you know if the comparison would be able to take advantage of the fact that those columns are partition keys in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will) I remember checking that data scanned would be the same as if those keys were explicitly specified)