# How effectively select data between 2 dates partitioned by year month day in presto?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, presto

There is a table with `y` (year), `m` month, `d` (day) column. How to select query between 2 date? Like:

```
select * from my_table where y m d between '2018-12-01' and '2021-01-01'
```

There are 2 problems here:

1. Using something the like `y >= '2018' AND m >= '12' AND d >= '01' AND y <= '2021' AND m <= '01' AND d <= '01'` lead to `m` must be more than `12` so no other month selected
2. Using date functions `date (date_parse(y || m || d, '%Y%m%d')) between  date (date_parse('20181201', '%Y%m%d'))  and date (date_parse('20210101', '%Y%m%d'))` - leads to `HIVE_EXCEEDED_PARTITION_LIMIT`. It looks like `between date` generates partitions for every second (millisecond?)

So how select with `between` date condition and do this effectively?

**Note**

I have added tag spark as well because presto run on top of spark - so problem should be general.

Comment: Since your dates are in ISO format you can just use string comparison and it should return the required result - `concat_ws('-', y, m,d) between '2018-12-01' and '2021-01-01'` should work.

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65899936/2700344

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a nested date partition schema is that selecting between two dates is never going to be easy, especially if your date range spans multiple months / years.

As of today I still haven't found a use case for which a nested schema is preferred w.r.t. a flat one.

As for your point #1, your query is wrong, you need to wrap your conditions in parentheses to make it work. It is doable but like I said, not a beautiful solution.

You can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT whatever
  FROM my_table
 WHERE (year = '2018' AND month = '12')
    OR (year BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020')
    OR (year = '2021' AND month = '01' AND day = '01')
```

As you can see it's all but simple. If you have the chance, I would restructure your database to have a flat partitioning schema with `yyyy-mm-dd` as your partition key. See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61067324/12127578).

Edit:

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58764960/12127578) answer, it seems it's possible to concat the year, month, day columns and use the `BETWEEN` operator, still taking advantage of the fact that those columns are partition keys.

Just to be sure, run both queries and check if the amount of data scanned stays the same, in which case, you can freely use `concat`.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

```
select * from my_table 
 where concat_ws('-',y, m, d) between '2018-12-01' and '2021-01-01'
```

Partition pruning works fine in this case and it looks much simpler